# ImageResizer triggering login redirect on a virtual directory

Tags: imageresizer

I am using Image resizer just fine in other areas of my site to resize local images, but when trying to resize an image that is in a virtual directory, I am getting the login screen. (Logging in does not change anything) If I add the '.ashx' extension, I get the same result.

The site is hosted on IIS 10 (integrated mode), with the appPool identity granted modify permissions on the site directory.  The virtual directory is using a network user that has modify permissions on the network folder.  The debug output does not show any errors -- I've posted the gist [[here]](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d26c6d907c58765bab35d522b40db9bd)

I can access images in the virtual directory without a resizing querystring (image.jpg instead of image.jpg?width=100) and the images are served up normally. However, as soon as I add a resizing command to the querystring, I get the login screen.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Does the AppPool identity have permissions on the network folder? Or do you have impersonation enabled?

Comment: No, since the appPool user is a local account, I can't (or don't know how to) add it to the permissions for the network folder. I don't have ASP.Net Impersonation enabled, but do have Anonymous and Forms authentication enabled.

Not sure if it was clear in my OP, but on the Virtual Directory, I have it connecting as a domain user on the network. When I test that, it seems to work (both on the 'Test Settings' in IIS and when I view an image on the website without the querystring)

Comment: You'll need to change the AppPool user account to have access to the network share. Otherwise IIS will be able to access the files, but .NET won't be able to. You can select which user account to use - I'd create a user account specifically for the app pool and give the the local and remote permissions required.

Comment: That did it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Nathanael had the solution above in the comments -- to solve the issue, I created a network user and granted modify privileges on the shared network folder to that user. I then set that same user as the application pool identity. Thanks for the help Nathanael!